# How to install ORCHARD CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm not sure if this question is not allowed, in the structure that I am asking it. However, I want to know if there is a way to manually install ORCHARD CMS the same way I would manually install wordpress. I am a very adequate wordpress/joomla/linux developer but have been tasked with installing orchard.

I've never worked with a microsoft server, however have one set up through my hosting company. Can I just drop the the zip files in and it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are four ways you can install Orchard. You can:**

Install it using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.
Install it from Microsoft WebMatrix as shown in [Working with Orchard in WebMatrix.](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Working-with-Orchard-in-WebMatrix/)
Download the Orchard [.zip](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/releases) file and install it as described in [Manually Installing Orchard Using a zip File.](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Manually-installing-Orchard-zip-file/)
[Enlist](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment/) in the Orchard source code and build Orchard from the command line or in Visual Studio.
This topic shows how to install Orchard using the Microsoft [Web Platform Installer.](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

**Requirements**

The minimum requirements for running Orchard are the following:

**ASP.NET 4.5**
A web server such as IIS Express 8, 7.5 or IIS 7.x.
When installing IIS, make sure you enable the ASP.NET IIS modules. Also make sure that you run Orchard in an integrated pipeline ASP.NET 4 application pool.

Important: If you previously installed any pre-release versions of WebMatrix, ASP.NET Web Pages, or ASP.NET MVC 4, you should uninstall those products before Orchard will run correctly on your computer. To develop Orchard sites, many developers will want to use a database such as SQL Server, and a web page programming environment such as WebMatrix or Visual Studio 2013. The following installation was tested with a clean installation of Windows 8.1. It uses the Web Platform Installer and it includes Orchard, IIS 8.0 Express, and optional applications for Orchard development like WebMatrix and SQL Server Compact 4.0.

**Installing Orchard**

To begin, download and install the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). When you're done, run it.

Find **Orchard CMS** and then click **Add** to include Orchard as an item to install.

[image]

Click **Install**. Accept the license terms in order to continue.

[image]

When the installation is complete, the dialog shows the list of installed tools in addition to Orchard. Click the **Launch** link to open the site in WebMatrix.

[image]

**Running Orchard in WebMatrix**

After WebMatrix starts, it should inmediately launch Orchard in the default browser. If not, you can launch Orchard by clicking the **Run** drop-down button, and selecting which browser to use. In WebMatrix you can click the **Files** workspace to see the contents of the Orchard site.

[image]

The first time Orchard is launched, you see in your browser the Orchard setup screen.
[image]

By default, Orchard includes a built-in database that you can use without installing a separate database server. However, if you are running SQL Server or SQL Server Express, you can configure Orchard to use either of those products instead by specifying a connection string. Optionally, you can enter a table prefix so that multiple Orchard installations can share the same database but keep their data separate.

[image]

The setup screen also includes a section where you can choose an Orchard recipe to set up your site. You can choose from the following Orchard recipes:

- **Default**. Sets up a site with frequently used Orchard features.
- **Blog**. Sets up a site as a personal blog.
- **Core**. Sets up a site that has only the Orchard framework for development use.
  [image]

Comment: This answer is a copy-paste of the documentation: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Installing-Orchard/

It should at least give attribution since it contains no added value.

Comment: I found the solution as per the question.Not copy paste stackoverflow questions and answers.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You copy-pasted your answer from the documentation site without attribution. In other words, this looks plagiarized. I'm sure you didn't mean any harm, in which case it would be easy to point to your source. It would also be useful to the questioner as it shows them where they could have found the answer themselves had they known where to look.